# Can DynamicProxy generator be used by multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using Castle DynamicProxy to back the business objects of an application. The server sends the values in a Dictionary, and we generate an interface for the objects from the database scheme. DynamicProxy creates objects to serve interface calls (field setters and getters) from the value dictionary. This way, we don't need to generate the property implementations and makes it easy to store data in the db.

My question is: Can I use a single proxy generator on multiple threads simoultenously? I looked at the documentation and the source code too, but I didn't find anything about this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, DynamicProxy `ProxyGenerator` can be used by multiple threads.